# Map Viewer: This page can't load Google Maps correctly

Tags: fiware, fiware-wirecloud

I am following up with the Wirecloud User Guide available here https://wirecloud.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/#managing-marketplaces.

However, Map Viewer failed to load correctly, tried different browsers, same result. Even though I set the desired location in the widget Settings, here's the settings I added:

```
Mark shadow radius  10
Initial Location    Santander, Spain
Zoom Level   17
Initial Zoom Level 14
```

I reloaded the map, yet location not loaded with a pop-up message saying

```
This page can't load Google Maps correctly.
```

Does anyone has idea why it fails to work correctly?

**EDIT:** Following image shows how the widget looks like when added.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a newer version of the `map-viewer` widget, current stable version is 2.6.2 and can be downloaded using this [link](https://github.com/Wirecloud/map-viewer-widget/releases/tag/2.6.2).

Once installed this new version, you have to obtain an API key from Google (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) and provide it on the widget preferences.

In any case, this is a bug in the WireCloud documentation, thanks for reporting it, it will be fixed as soon as possible.